# pivot table sort datetime column

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have the following part of sql statement to  pivot dynamic columns. The number of columns (ClosingDate) is variable :

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ClosingDate + '_'+ c.col) 
                      from #TmpT 
                      cross apply 
                      (
                        select 'Cnt' col
                        union all
                        select 'TT'
                      ) c 
            FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE         
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

The problem is that `ClosingDate` columns get converted to `varchar` and they are ordered as `varchar`, not as `date` .

Is there a way to order by `datetime` ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting them to dates yourself first:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + 
                             QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),ClosingDate,112) + '_'+ c.col) 
                      from #TmpT 
                      cross apply 
                      (
                        select 'Cnt' col
                        union all
                        select 'TT'
                      ) c 
            FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE         
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: It actually worked. I pass the ClosingDate field already in the format CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),ClosingDate,112) and the query still order the dates as varchar, but since the format is yyyymmdd the dates are ordered secuentially. Many thanks!